# Windows phone 7.8 : can't download picture in background agent

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use a background task in my Windows Phone app to generate the live tile image. To do this, I download a picture, save it to the isolated storage, and then set the live tile to use this picture. (I don't set the live tile to use the image url because I also modify it before saving it)

I use a WebClient that works perfectly well on Windows Phone 8 to download the picture :

```
var wc = new WebClient();                
using (var stream = await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync(imageUri))
{
// Image modifications and saving
}
```

When I use the same code in the WP7.8 version of the app, it doesn't work : the live tile is updated if the code is launched while the app is running, but not in the background agent.

When I debug the background agent, the code just stops on the OpenReadTaskAsync line, without throwing any exception.

The picture is not big (less than 400 x 400px, 70kb), I don't understand why I can't download it.

Is the WP7.8 background agent more limited than WP8 ?
Do you see any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: You should put a breakpoint on the call to `NotifyComplete()` in your background agent. My guess is that it somehow gets called before the end of your `OpenReadTaskAsync`, thus ending the agent prematurely.

Comment: Oh yes, that's exactly the problem :) Thanks ! (and I will review the WP8 code, the bug is probably there too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a breakpoint on the call to `NotifyComplete()` in your background agent. My guess is that it somehow gets called before the end of your `OpenReadTaskAsync`, thus ending the agent prematurely.